# How to skip @PostPersist or @PostUpdate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am using methods with @PostPersist and @PostUpdate annotations.
However in Only One certain case, I would like to not call that method during saving entity.

Is there a possibility to somehow wrap particular entityRepository.save to not call methods I mentioned earlier? In any other cases my postpersist and postupdate should work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a boolean field in the entity that signals listeners should be skipped. Set that flag in your use case and use `if (!skip) { ... }` in the listeners. There is no other way.